# Deploying website to Customer localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

I developed Store Management software but as web application (asp.net-MVC),I want to publish it to a customer localhost to run like desktop application ,I published it to my PC Localhost and it work correctly , What is i need to make it run on customer Localhost correctly? , do i need IIS and SQLServer and Visual Studio or i don't need Visual Studio , and is there A tool to run database on customer PC more simple than SQLSever

Answer (score 0):

You can take the WebDeploy package and deploy it to any IIS instance which includes IIS express.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=IISExpress

However, I would suggest looking at ASP.NET Core instead, as it does not require IIS and can run self-hosted.  Its not publicly released yet but getting closer every day.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/

Regarding the database, I would suggest SQLite which is a file-based SQL database.